# Regarding the recalc in question rep increase what happens due to the cap?

Tags: discussion, reputation

When the recalc runs what happens regarding rep capping on particular days? Say I earned 200 solely from questions on one day, will I earn a further 200 when the recalc runs or will I earn zero?

On a similar note if I got no rep from a question upvote on a day will the recalc give me 10, 5 or 0 rep?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The recalc process correctly handles the rep cap. The rules are somewhat complicated, but if you earned 200 from question upvotes in a day (and nothing else) you will still earn 200 for that day after the recalc finishes. (So no change.) It essentially simulates each day for each user.

Also, you should earn the badges for rep capping if that happened under the new payout system. But it might take a day or two for the badge-awarding process to run.

I'm not sure I understand the second paragraph, but hopefully I managed to answer it along the way.

Comment: The second paragraph  meant to ask what happens if the question upvote came in after I hit the cap but I missed some words out it seems. This answers it anyway with you saying the cap is correctly handled.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder: Good deal. The rep cap rules are what make recalculation so complicated. Thankfully we have some experience thanks to [Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356294/removing-documentation-reputation-archive-and-links).

Comment: Is the recalculation still going on? Will it affect all SE sites?

Comment: @Renan: Yes it is, but for now it's just on MSE. We're working through some problems as we speak.

Comment: @jon are there any thoughts to fixing the blog post to correct the launch date from 2007 to 2008?

Answer (score 9):

When recalculations happen, they are performed as if "it was always this way." If you got 40 question upvotes in one day, the amount you earned that day will not change. If you got 20 answer upvotes and 20 question upvotes in a day, the first 20 upvotes (regardless of Q or A) will give you reputation, and the rest will have no effect.

Don't think of this as you *earning* more reputation today, think of it as history being modified so that you *earned* more reputation in the past.