# Will the reputation I retrospectively gain count toward my "rep cap" badge?

Tags: support, reputation, badges, daily-reputation-limit

[As of today](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/), receiving an upvote on your question will give you 10 points of reputation instead of 5.

The whole reputation of any user is being recalculated and is taking into account the "[200 daily rep cap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32160/400547)".

Does that also mean that I will gain some "step" toward the achievement of the "Earn 200 daily reputation" badges?

Since the recalculation is taking into account "rep cap", it sounds fair that I should also win steps toward the badges, but I would like to know for sure (I case SE Inc forgot about that ^^)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If the recalculation causes you to reach 200 reputation on new days, then yes, your progress towards the badges will increase. There is no "tick" that gets added to a day when you hit it before. Each time the process for that badge runs, it just looks for how many days you achieved 200 reputation and sets that as the count for your badge progress.

Comment: I believe the process for recalculating reputation is different from the one for awarding/calculating progress towards badges so their could be a delay before badges are awarded.

Comment: @StrongBad That has indeed been confirmed on this answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338124/400547 "it might take a day or two for the badge-awarding process to run"