# Reputation recalculation didn't retroactively award Mortarboard

Tags: bug, badges, daily-reputation-limit, daily-reputation-badges

With the recalculation of reputation due to the update to rep gained from questions, there are a few stacks where I hit the daily reputation cap, where I didn't before.

Take for example [this profile.](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/21996/jad?tab=summary) In the progress bar for the Epic badge, this is shown:

[image]

Mortarboard, however, has not been awarded.

Is this a bug? Or was retroactively checking for that badge deemed not worth the effort?

Comment: I've found that even under normal loads, it can sometimes take quite a while for a badge to be awarded. For example, I believe it was about 4 or 5 hours after I fulfilled the requirements that I got the [Electorate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/54/electorate) badge, although I think it was due to when this was next checked. However, with all of the various recent recalculations & other background work, including many new badges, due to the question upvote change from +5 to +10, I suspect it'll take even longer than normal, but you should still get your new badge(s) eventually.

Comment: I read somewhere (from a staff member) that, after the recalculation, the awarding of such a badge might take a day or two. So this *could* be normal.

Comment: "it might take a day or two for the badge-awarding process to run." https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338124/400547

Comment: @BelovedFool that explains. I wasn't aware when exactly the recalculation had taken place. I'll leave this up untill the badge pops up, but if all goes right, this can be [tag:status-norepro].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like it has just been fixed:

[image]

Also visible in profile, e.g. from https://superuser.com/users/116475/franck-dernoncourt?tab=badges&sort=recent:

[image]

Comment: They *might* be showing up in the Achievements Notification but I don't see them awarded in either of your profiles or on the [recently awarded badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges) list.

Comment: @Rob added in answer

Comment: It says that your last one was in 2016: https://superuser.com/help/badges/43/mortarboard?userid=116475

Comment: @Rob good catch, unsure what's going on.

Comment: I don't doubt that you see them, but I (we) can't, which is still a bug.

Comment: @Rob wait, I think it says 2016 because it's retroactive. So that seems to make sense.

Comment: Or, [you, on Arcade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/144/mortarboard?userid=19400) in 2014, and everyone else - none for 5 days:   https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/144/mortarboard

Comment: I'm in favor of leaving it for the Devs, there are a couple of close votes (I came here from Review), so I thought I'd clairify that it's not clear it's working and JAD should have some input.

Comment: @Rob I believe it's 2014 and 2016 because it's retroactive.

Comment: Then why would I have [Mortarboard from last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/50/mortarboard?userid=282094) and no notification? - It's broken for one of us, or your retroactive theory needs refinement. :)

Comment: @Rob Did the badge appear today or last year?

Comment: I'll need to set aside more time and come back to this later, the badge appeared on the date shown in the Url and as I recall a notification at the time, and not another today. I should have more time available in a few hours.

Comment: I got one awarded from 2015 today, so I'm pretty sure this is all expected.

Comment: I [earned one Mortarboard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/50/mortarboard?userid=282094), "Awarded Aug 7 '18 at 23:52". Yet when I do [my own reputation recalculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edBwC.jpg) I'm short one bronze badge. It would take more time than it's worth to request the badge for myself but it's important to mention that there's a bug somewhere here, for the benefit of correctness and others.

Comment: @tchrist thanks for the edit, FYI one can use `<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qskt0.jpg" width="200" />` to avoid lossy compression.

Comment: I just won a "Mortarboard" on history. So it indeed seems to be fixed (I checked and saw the badge in my profile page too)